# I need to remove the .php extension with godaddy hosting

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, web-config

I am at a loss, have tried **.htaccess** which seems to only work on my server, when uploaded to my hosting account, nothing but a big 404 error; I did more research and learned about **web.config** for godaddy users, still nothing. I am new at using this method, tried numerous rewrite codes, changing the extensions, researching, you name it. Maybe I'm not understanding exactly how to place the files when uploading; I did read threads on here and still I'm missing something.

this is the objective:
site.com/index.php
to 
site.com/index

here are examples of what i used to accomplish my goal
.htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#Fix Rewrite
Options -MultiViews
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

web.config:

```
<configuration> 
 <system.webServer>
  <rewrite> 
<rules>  
<rule name="RewritePHP"> <match url="(.*)" /> 
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll"> 
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />  
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />      
</conditions> <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" /> </rule>  
</rules>    
  </rewrite>
 </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: `web.config` is for IIS/asp.net servers. it means absolutely nothing to Apache, and similarly .htaccess has absolutely no meaning to IIS.

Comment: I needed the web.config for this because I am using a windows based, actually figured it out literally after writing this post. I took the web.config i created with the above code, added it the website's directory, problem solved